# Laravel path directory symbols means

Tags: laravel, path, directory

What does the symbol "~" and the dot "." mean in here:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` is called a *tilde* sign and in a path on unix it stands for the **home directory** of the current user

So the path could be written as:

```
/home/root/.composer/vendor/bin
```

The dot in ".composer" has no special meaning when it comes to specifying the path. The folder is just called that way.

However directories and files starting with a dot are hidden. For example when you run `ls` you won't see them.

Comment: Plus 1 - The dot *does* have a special meaning. By default, files/directories starting with a dot are hidden.

Comment: @JosephSilber That's right. I meant no special meaning in terms of the path itself, but I will definitely add that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to do with Laravel. It's a unix path. `~`  = user's home directory, e.g. it's a shortcut version for something like

```
/home/username/.composer/vendor/bin
```